# Windows 10 doesn't switch off screen after computer is locked

Tags: windows-10, display, lock

Whenever I lock my computer, I would expect the screen to switch off after a little while, at least I think that's how it used to work. But for some time now, Windows 10 is no longer doing this, the screen will stay on even after several hours.

Any idea how to make it switch off the screen after the computer is locked (after a minute or two for example).

Comment: Have you tried to switch to another power profile or create one from scratch?

Comment: Have you configured your power plan to turn the monitor off?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround mentioned here: [How to lock Windows 10 and turn off the display with one click](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-lock-windows-10-and-turn-off-the-display-with-one-click/)

It involves using a script to provide the functionality to simultaneously lock your PC and turn off the monitor instantly.

Requirements

- A  freeware tool, [Nirsoft Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), which allows you to control various OS and features from the command line.

Workthrough

- Create a create a new *.VBS file using notepad.
- Copy and paste the following text into Notepad:

---

```
`'Lock PC and Turn off Display
'************************

Dim WSHShell

Set WSHShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WSHShell.Run "Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation", 0

WSHShell.Run "nircmd.exe monitor async_off", 0`
```

- In Notepad, click File menu -> Save item. The "Save as" dialog will appear. Browse for the desired folder wish to store the script and type "lock.vbs" with quotes in the File Name text box (the double quotes are that the file gets directly saved as "lock.vbs" and not "lock.vbs.txt"):
- Put nircmd.exe you downloaded earlier in the same folder. You can also copy the NirCmd.exe into your directory. This is important so that all scripts can easily find its EXE file.

Now double click the "lock.vbs" file. You Windows 10 PC will be locked and the screen will be turned off.